# Bowling scores program

Tags: python

I am having trouble completing this program. This program is supposed to have a team of 4 members. Each member bowls a total of 3 games.

I need to write a program that asks each member their name and asks them for each of their 3 games for each member. These names need to be saved in a text file called "bowling.txt" and display them. Another separate program should be written to read the records from the "bowling.txt" file and should also display the average score for each bowler.

This is my program so far:

```
# This program will ask
# the user for
# bowling scores 'W'.

def game(bowling):
    bowling_file = open('bowling.txt', 'w')
    for count in range(1, 5, + 1):
        print('Enter the name and the score for each game for member #', 
             count, sep='')
        name = input('Name: ')
        game1 = input('Score for game 1: ')
        game2 = input('Score for game 2: ')
        game3 = input('Score for game 3: ')

        bowling_file.write(name + '\n')
        bowling_file.write(game1 + '\n')
        bowling_file.write(game2 + '\n')
        bowling_file.write(game3 + '\n')

    print()
    bowling_file.close()
    print('All games have been printed to bowling.txt')

def main():
    game('')

main()
```

-----------------This is the separate 'R' file---------------

```
# This program will keep
# bowling scores 'R'.
def game(bowling):
    bowling_file = open('bowling.txt', 'r')

    total = 0
    NumLines = 0
    line = bowling_file.readline()

    while line != "":
        NumLines += 1
        bowling = int(line)
        total += bowling
        print(bowling)
        line = bowling_file.readline()
        average = total / NumLines

    print('The average score for member #', count, sep='')
    average = total / NumLines  
def main():
    game('bowling.txt')

main()
```

Comment: First, what is the problem you're trying to solve? Without running this code, there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong with it. If there's a bug somewhere, tell us what it is—does it raise an exception, or output different results than you expected? If there's a missing part that you don't know how to write, where is it missing, what is it supposed to do, and what are you stuck on?

Comment: One minor thing: Your "W" program passes a `bowling` argument to `game`, which is ignored, and you pass an empty string. Surely this should be the filename, like it is in the "R" program?

Comment: Another minor thing: Instead of doing that `readline`, then a `while line != ""`, then another readline inside the loop, you can just do `for line in bowling_file:`

Comment: yes sorry, once I go to the 'R' file and run it, it does not work. it says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'john 1\n'", since It asks for a name. I cant get past that and don't know how to fix it. Then I can't figure out how to average each member score separately.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to debug a program when you don't know what the error is, but I see one pretty obvious problem.

In the "W" program, you write four things for each player:

```
bowling_file.write(name + '\n')
bowling_file.write(game1 + '\n')
bowling_file.write(game2 + '\n')
bowling_file.write(game3 + '\n')
```

In the "R" program, you just read lines and try to turn them all into `int`s. That's going to fail on the very first line, because it's not an `int`, it's a name.

Also, you're not looping over the number of players, or the number of games per player; you're just trying to use all of the lines as games for a single player. Not to mention that you never set that `count` variable, which is presumably supposed to be the player number.

So, you could do something like this, just like in your "W" program:

```
for count in range(1, 5, + 1):
    name = bowling_file.readline()
    game1 = int(bowling_file.readline()) 
    game2 = int(bowling_file.readline()) 
    game3 = int(bowling_file.readline()) 
    average = (game1 + game2 + game3) / 3
    print('The average score for member #', count, ' is ', average, sep='')
```